# USB device is not visible inside Vagrant

Tags: windows, vagrant

I tried to make visible USB device inside Vagrant (OS: Windows 10) that's why I added these two lines to Vagrant file

```
 vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--usb', 'on']
 # Provider-specific configuration so you can fine-tune various
 # backing providers for Vagrant. These expose provider-specific options.
 # Example for VirtualBox:
 config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
 #   # Display the VirtualBox GUI when booting the machine
 vb.gui = true
 #   # Configure dongle
 vb.customize ['modifyvm', :id, '--usb', 'on']
 vb.customize ['usbfilter', 'add', '0', '--target', :id, '--name', 'VC', '--vendorid', '0x046E', '--productid', '0x0001']
```

end

But when I use `vagrant up` I am unable to see this USB device. It marks as unknown devices in VirtualBox device manager. Device is visible on local PC and sometimes it becomes visible after several `vagrant reload` commands. But I am looking for stable solution which gives me ability to make USB device visible as soon as machine is booted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Here is short PowerShell script which is based on using devcon tool.

```
# Set location where devcon tool is placed

 Set-Location "D:\MSSDK\Tools\x64"

# Disconnect USB from host machine

.\devcon.exe remove *VID_096E*

# Reconect USB to virtual machine

.\devcon.exe rescan
```

devcon.exe is a part of MS SDK toolkit. You can remove and connect any USB device even without its physical disconnection. After USB is disconnected from host machine I do rescan and after USB device is visible inside VirtualBox.

Answer (score 10):

This can be accomplished via the VirtualBox Settings -> USB -> USB Device Filters, or by defining the properties via the `Vagrantfile`.

The `usermod` definition allows user access to USB devices via the VirtualBox Extension Pack that implements USB integration between the host and guest machine.

Before starting a VM with `vagrant up` run the following commands:

```
# You need the virtualbox-extensions package to enable USB
sudo apt install virtualbox-ext-pack # accept the license to install
# add host user to 'vboxusers' group
sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER
# You will need to logout and back in or reboot to get access to USB
# Make sure you have the stuff below in your Vagrantfile, then:
vagrant up
```

**Note :- $USER should resolve to the current user on the host machine.**

Before defining the attributes for USB integration in the Vagrantfile you should run `VBoxManage` to help get you the USB information currently mounted on host machine:

```
sudo VBoxManage list usbhost

[sudo] password for rohan: 
Host USB Devices:

UUID:               xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
VendorId:           0x0781 (0781)
ProductId:          0x5575 (5575)
Revision:           1.39 (0139)
Port:               0
USB version/speed:  2/2
Manufacturer:       SanDisk
Product:            Cruzer Glide
SerialNumber:       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Address:            sysfs:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1//device:/dev/vboxusb/001/011
Current State:      Busy
```

Now, the Vagrantfile can implement the configuration attributes (determined above):

```
 # Enable USB Controller on VirtualBox
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usb", "on"]
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--usbehci", "on"]
  end

  # Implement determined configuration attributes
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["usbfilter", "add", "0",
        "--target", :id,
        "--name", "Any Cruzer Glide",
        "--product", "Cruzer Glide"]
  end
```

If any more results or any modification needed to be done on the attributes then add values in `config.vm.provider` according to `VBoxManage`

Following are the properties you can define with respect to `usbfilter`:

```
usbfilter                 add <index,0-N>
                            --target <uuid|vmname>|global
                            --name <string>
                            --action ignore|hold (global filters only)
                            [--active yes|no] (yes)
                            [--vendorid <XXXX>] (null)
                            [--productid <XXXX>] (null)
                            [--revision <IIFF>] (null)
                            [--manufacturer <string>] (null)
                            [--product <string>] (null)
                            [--remote yes|no] (null, VM filters only)
                            [--serialnumber <string>] (null)
                            [--maskedinterfaces <XXXXXXXX>]
```

After defining above the USB device can be mounted on guest machine upon `vagrant halt`, followed by `vagrant up`, or `vagrant provision`, followed by `vagrant reload`.

> **Note**: Since USB devices may vary from time to time, it is difficult to predict ahead of time, which device should be defined
>   within the Vagrantfile. Therefore, defining a USB filter via the
>   VirtualBox GUI (Settings > USB > USB Device Filters), is many times
>   preferred over the above Vagrantfile implementation.

**Ref** : [using terminal](https://github.com/jeff1evesque/machine-learning/wiki/Vagrant), [using UI](https://github.com/jeff1evesque/iScanner/issues/30#issuecomment-98148465)

Comment: sorry for long reply. Thank you for your mini tutorial. Unfortunately it's not a solution because my goal is not to do something by my hand but to automate the hole process. And I found solution.

`# Set location where devcon tool is placed

Set-Location "D:\MSSDK\Tools\x64"

# Disconnect USB dongle from host machine

.\devcon.exe remove *VID_096E*

# Reconect USB dongle to virtual machine

.\devcon.exe rescan`

By using devcon.exe tool (which is part of MS SDK toolkit) I disconnected USB on program level and reconnect USB to Vagrant machine.

Comment: It works at 100% because for some reason USB device is stuck to host machine and marked as "Uknown device" in VirtualBox. So I connect and reconnect - and now everything works as expected.